# Confusion about Python list result

Tags: python

Here's the code:

```
a=[1,2,3]
a[1]=10,20,30
print a
a[1:2]=10,20,30
print a
a[1:2]=[10,20,30]
print a
```

The result is:

```
[1, (10, 20, 30), 3]
[1, 10, 20, 30, 20, 30]
[1, 10, 20, 30, 20, 30, 3]
```

Can anyone tell me what happened?

Comment: The result *of what* is ?

Comment: Oh the result of list "a" in each step. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a=[1,2,3]
print a
a[1]=10,20,30  # add a tuple at position 1
print a  
a[1:2]=10,20,30 #replaces tuple and inserts 10,20,30 at position 1
print a  
a[1:2]=[10,20,30] #now a[1:2] is 10 so this replaces 10 and inserts 10,20,30 at position 1 
print a
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, (10, 20, 30), 3]
[1, 10, 20, 30, 3]
[1, 10, 20, 30, 20, 30, 3]
```

Note: There is never a 30 at the end. 
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

You should probably review [slicing notation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/introduction.html#lists). In a nutshell, your first operation created a list. Your second operation inserted a tuple at index 1. Your third operation replaced a list slice with the contents of a tuple, while the fourth operation replaced a list slice with the contents of another list.

Comment: Thank you. Just got three more questions: 1. Why the second operation is "insert" but not "replace the element at offset 1"? 2. In the third operation, my slice just have size one, but the tuple have size three, why they all inserted successfully? 3. Why a[1::-1]=10,20,30 get an error?

Comment: 1. I probably should have said replace rather than insert. 2.  A list holds a collection of objects, and a tuple is an object that may be inserted. 3. The  slice you're inserting into is too small based on the slicing notation you're using.

Comment: I mean, it looks like "a[1:2]=10,20,30" inserted three elements 10,20,30 instead of one tuple (10,20,30), but the slice a[1:2] just have size 1. Shouldn't it be too small to insert? Like a[1::-1]?

Comment: 10,20,30 is a tuple. It's the commas that make it a tuple not the parentheses. The parentheses are only required then there is ambiguity, e.g. in function calls.